# Deploying an Angular project with several projects in localhost with endpoints (nginx/apache)

Tags: angular, apache, nginx-config, raspberry-pi4

I have a problem displaying a **Angular build** project. Whether it's Apache or Nginx, it's the same error, I think the alias is doing something wrong but I don't know how to fix it :/

My goal is to have several projects deployed, in localhost with endpoints on my raspberry, including the one in Angular that doesn't work

```bash
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /angular-project {
        alias /var/www/angular-project;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /angular-project/index.html;
    }

    location /another-project-without-framework {
        alias /var/www/another-project-without-framework;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /another-project-without-framework/index.html;
    }
}
```

#### Web console

```json
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
polyfills.abdd3bd5549f92a5.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.57705c3bf87b0854.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.a351c429be76225a.css:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.a351c429be76225a.css:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

#### Nginx console

```json
request: "GET /styles.a351c429be76225a.css HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.14", referrer: "http://192.168.1.14/angular-project/"
2023/07/15 23:06:23 [error] 3757#3757: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/runtime.bc0b2030e3e0ddc9.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.11, server: localhost, request: "GET /runtime.bc0b2030e3e0ddc9.js HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.14", referrer: "http://192.168.1.14/angular-project/"
2023/07/15 23:06:23 [error] 3757#3757: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/polyfills.abdd3bd5549f92a5.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.11, server: localhost, request: "GET /polyfills.abdd3bd5549f92a5.js HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.14", referrer: "http://192.168.1.14/angular-project/"
2023/07/15 23:06:23 [error] 3757#3757: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/main.57705c3bf87b0854.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.11, server: localhost, request: "GET /main.57705c3bf87b0854.js HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.14", referrer: "http://192.168.1.14/angular-project/"
2023/07/15 23:06:23 [error] 3757#3757: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/styles.a351c429be76225a.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.11, server: localhost, request: "GET /styles.a351c429be76225a.css HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.14", referrer: "http://192.168.1.14/angular-project/"
```

On the logs when I redirect to the localhost/angular-project endpoint, it tells me that there is the index.html, but not the .js and .css files.

However, I did authorise the file as follows:

```bash
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/angular-project
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/angular-project
```

And `angular-project` works fine with this nginx config (and on apache too):

```bash
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /var/www/angular-project;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help! :)